# Can other PCs use Alchemical Weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, crafting, alchemist

I wanted to get some clarity on something. My character is an alchemist for reference.

**If I craft Alchemical Weapons like those listed in the Alchemists Manual, can my other party members use them?**

For example if I wanted to make some alchemical arrows for our rogue, would there be a rule against them using it? I know I have to take a special feat to allow my party to use Extracts, but I haven't found anything stating the same is true for alchemical items (bombs excluded).

I'm sure my GM would be okay with it, but he doesn't want to make a bunch of exceptions to written rules.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes.

[Alchemical Weapons](https://www.aonprd.com/EquipmentMisc.aspx?Category=AlchemicalWeapons) are a category of gear that is available to any character, not just Alchemists.

To clarify, the [Alchemist](https://www.aonprd.com/ClassDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Alchemist) class was introduced in the [Advanced Player's Guide](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/v5748btpy8fo1) (APG), however prior to that alchemical items, such as [Alchemist's Fire](https://www.aonprd.com/EquipmentMiscDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Alchemist%27s%20fire), existed in the [Core Rulebook](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/v5748btpy88yj) under the category of "Special Substances and Items" in the equipment section, which essentially consisted of items that [Craft (Alchemy)](https://www.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ItemName=Craft) could make.

As a preface to the section the items are contained in, it was written:

> Beyond armor and weapons, a character can carry a whole variety of gear, from rations (to sustain him on long travels), to rope (which is useful in countless circumstances). Most of the common gear carried by adventurers is summarized on Table 6–9.

Given this preface, these items are definitely intended for the common adventurer to have and use, not just alchemists.

---

To explain how they became known as a Alchemical Weapons.

When Paizo released [Ultimate Equipment](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8tmc?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Ultimate-Equipment), they republished a lot of the items from previous books including alchemical ones, in this book they decided to classify items crafted via Craft (Alchemy) for the intent of harming others as Alchemical Weapons. Thus, giving us the category of equipment we now know as Alchemical Weapons.